# XSLT Select with 2 contains

Tags: xslt, contains

We are using the following to select all nodes where 'ExperienceInfo' contains '582':

```
<xsl:apply-templates disable-output-escaping="yes" select="td:Benutzer_zu_Gastro[contains(td:ExperienceInfo, '582')]">
```

And this to select all nodes where 'Kategorien' contains 'Restaurant':

```
<xsl:apply-templates disable-output-escaping="yes" select="td:Benutzer_zu_Gastro[contains(td:Kategorien, 'Restaurant')]">
```

How do we combine the two into ONE statement so that ONLY nodes are selected where ExperienceInfo contains 582 AND Kategorien contains Restaurant?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: xsl:apply-templates does not accept a disable-output-escaping attribute, and any conformant XSLT processor should give you an error on this. (I've come across people sprinkling disable-output-escaping all over their xsl:value-of instructions like some kind of magic fairy dust, but this is ridiculous...)

Comment: Thanks for tip Michael. We'll avoid it the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so simple that you must have thought "no, that can't be it":

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="
  td:Benutzer_zu_Gastro[
    contains(td:ExperienceInfo, '582') 
    and contains(td:Kategorien, 'Restaurant')
  ]
">
```

If your XML looks like `<td:ExperienceInfo>582</td:ExperienceInfo>` (etc.) it can be made even simpler.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="
  td:Benutzer_zu_Gastro[
    td:ExperienceInfo = '582' and td:Kategorien = 'Restaurant'
  ]
">
```

Two general notes

- if your XML has delimited lists like `<td:ExperienceInfo>582,693</td:ExperienceInfo>` (please say it doesn't) you will need to use `contains()` but it might be a good idea to include the separator character to avoid false positives:

  ```js
  contains(concact(',', td:ExperienceInfo, ','), ',582,')
  ```
- `disable-output-escaping="yes"` is not a standard feature of XSLT processors. As Michael Kay points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588923/#comment25596980_17588923), it's not even syntactically valid on `<xsl:apply-templates>` in the first place.
  Try to get rid of it. *Sometimes* it can't be avoided, but often it indicates a design flaw - it enables output of ill-formed XML and is a sign of improper separation of data and structure.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak! You are absolutely right: too easy to think that could really be the solution :) Thanks also for the concact info. I think we'll be needing more of that soon, also regexp as the XML we're transforming is often endless streams of strings. Great answer!